# Vue router scrollBehavior

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Имеется несколько роутов. Задача - сохранять положение каждой страницы при переходе от роута к роутоу в том положении, в котором страница оставалась на момент перехода. Результат необходим как в этом демо-примере: https://jeneser.github.io/vue-scroll-behavior/#/hello

В документации указанно, что:

> Возврат savedPosition позволяет эмулировать нативное поведение
>   браузера при использовании кнопок назад/вперёд

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition
  } else {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
}
```

Но по факту это не всегда работает, периодически положение страницы остается в непонятном положении при использовании кнопок браузера назад и вперед. При программной навигации при нажатии кнопок с использованием **to="/route-name"** также происходит непонятная картина - иногда положение сохраняется, а иногда нет. Пока не могу понять с чем это связано и от чего зависит. Помогите разобраться в данном вопросе

Answer (score 1):

scrollBehavior раньше времени срабатывает - по этому через таймер пробуй

```
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    // console.log(savedPosition)
    let position = {x: 0, y: 0}
    if (savedPosition) {
        position = savedPosition
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(position)
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Comment: Это помогло. Только с таймером происходит скачек - сначала страница поднимается вверх, а через секунду опускается до необходимого места. Минимальную задержку удалось выставить на уровне 300 мс. Интересно, почему нельзя ниже и с чем это может быть связано?